# Play framework : rjs not found

Tags: playframework-2.0

I just followed posts online to add minification support in my play app. This is my `plugins.sbt`:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.3.5")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.0.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-uglify" % "1.0.3")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-gzip" % "1.0.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.7")
```

And this is my `build.sbt`:

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, SbtWeb)

pipelineStages := Seq(rjs, uglify, digest, gzip)
```

But I get this error:

```
.../build.sbt:81: error: not found: value rjs
pipelineStages := Seq(rjs, uglify, digest, gzip)
                      ^
[error] Type error in expression
```

This somewhow works:

```
pipelineStages := Seq(uglify, digest, gzip)
```

On a sidenote, it doesn't minify the JS. It is only creating gzip objects, and `Assets.versioned` is generating the URLs with the weird hash-like ids. Isn't uglify supposed to minify the JS?

So apparently, rjs is what I need to minify the JS/CSS. Every single article online (including the docs on sbt-rjs) ask me to just add `pipelineStages := Seq(rjs, ..)`, but why am I getting the error that `not found: value rjs`?

Comment: Have you posted your `plugins.sbt` and `build.sbt` absolutely verbatim?  I can't see what would cause this unless there's an issue with your `plugins.sbt` not being picked up correctly. For reference, here's one that "works for me": https://gist.github.com/mikesname/e78e08d0618b27dbd29a

Comment: Absolutely. I have copied and pasted it. After reading your comment, I checked it once again and it is exactly what it is.

Comment: I asked because I was under the impression you need to have blank lines in between each `addSbtPlugin` statements (as you should between each statement in the `build.sbt` file). Maybe post the directory structure of your project to ensure all the config files are being picked up correctly?

Comment: Oh, I just removed those lines for the sake of the question. So, technically, not "verbatim". This is the directory structure (alongwith the build files): http://i.imgur.com/sg48ZHK.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into this issue as I was hastily trying to configure it and inserted:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.7")
```

when

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.1")
```

already existed in the file. So basically it was the duplicate that was causing the issue. Hopefully no one else makes the same mistake :-)

Comment: Dude! You are a godsend! Thank you so so much.. I can't believe that I made the EXACT same mistake. The error messages on sbt sometimes are just so awful and useless.